# Not decrypting value for varchar datatype column by using DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE function

Tags: sql-server

```
create table login_details(uid integer,username varchar(10),password varchar(100))
create table login_details1(uid integer,username varchar(10),password varbinary(100))
insert into login_details(uid,username,password) values(1,'smith',convert(nvarchar (100),EncryptByPassPhrase('kiran','XXX'),1))
insert into login_details(uid,username,password) values(1,'smith',convert(nvarchar (100),EncryptByPassPhrase('kiran','YYY'),1))

insert into login_details1(uid,username,password) values(1,'smith',EncryptByPassPhrase('kiran','XXX'))
insert into login_details1(uid,username,password) values(1,'smith',EncryptByPassPhrase('kiran','YYY'))

select convert( varchar(20),DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('kiran',cast(password as nvarchar(1)))),* from login_details
select convert( varchar(20),DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE ('kiran',password))  ,* from login_details1
```

in my first table login_details password columns datatype  is varchar  in that case encryption happen while inserting record by using EncryptByPassPhrase function

but when i am  selecting record by using DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE function value is not decrypting

same in  case of login_details1 tables password columns datatype  is varbinary so encryption decryption happening

but i want to do same in case of login_details where password columns datatype  is varchar

Comment: Your question is ambiguous, please take a little more time in adding more details to the question, take care of proper wording and even add some examples of data, if you think they can help in understanding the problem. Otherwise, in time, your question might get closed due to low content quality and you won't be able to get an answer.

Comment: Why are you storing passwords that could be decrypted in the first place? Also, why are you casting `password` to an `nvarchar(1)`?